# how add public key to ssh-agent permanently

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I added my existed public key to ssh-agent but after restarting I need to run

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

to add it again. Is there a way to add it permanently?

Comment: You could just add that line to your bashrc

Comment: thanks works perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that. You would need some secure store for the passphrase and you don't have it in `ssh-agent`. By storing the passphrase in plaintext, you basically downgrade the security to none (and you would better do by removing the passphrase completely).

There are applications in GNOME that store the passphrase securely encrypted with the account password (`gnome-keyring`, `seahorse`), but pure `ssh-agent` does not know that.