# How to permanently add SSH key for lcoal git (github) repository?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I'm using SSH key to secure push/fetch data from my github repository.
But now I start ssh-agent and add ssh key every terminal start. It's annoying.
In new terminal I get `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).` error trying to push/fetch data, until I start ssh-agent doing `eval "($ssh-agent -s)"` and add ssh key doing `ssh-add {path to key}`. Can I add the key permanently? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64865626/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393756/7976758 and scan through https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh-agent%5D+permanently

Comment: @phd, yeah, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I should just have added this lines into the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```